# Can we create user-defined function in crystal report that can be accessible or used in all reports like crystal reports built in functions?

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

I want to create a function in crystal report that will format person name e.g. LastName, FirstName or FirstName,LastName according to giving settings. How can I use my function in all crystal reports like its own built-in functions?